# Is this the correct way to undertake Z-Tests on average user ratings to compare different versions of products?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mean, z-test, z-score

The below is a partial data set showing the mean user ratings for a number of products, each of which is available in a number of standard versions, e.g. a common feature added to each product such as adding electric windows to a car.

Each mean rating is comprised of circa 17 user ratings, though some are more. The user ratings were submitted on a scale from -100 to +100. N/A indicates a product which is not available in that particular version. I understand from [this question I asked previously](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/229243/when-to-replace-not-applicable-or-n-a-values-with-a-zero) that I should not replace the N/A values with a 0 or an average.

The data is continuous interval type data.

```
             Control   V1        V2        V3        V4        V5        V6
Product 1    1.63     -5.19     -0.48     5.79      8.89      4.19      15.73
Product 2    0.60     0.84      4.47      N/A       0.52      21.17     N/A
Product 3    4.53     -15.20    -19.66    N/A       2.84      N/A       13.07
Product 4    7.30     17.53     20.25     17.04     N/A       4.60      9.28
Product 5    -4.05    -21.33    -14.00    -13.00    N/A       -23.71    -8.71
Product 6    26.27    14.53     N/A       21.24     N/A       27.25     35.18
Product 7    -3.12    N/A       N/A       N/A       N/A       7.88      17.38

Mean Ratings 4.74     -1.47     -1.88     7.77      4.08      6.90      13.66
```

**I want to compare the effect of the different standard versions compared to the control.**

So, I think I should be using two tailed Z-Tests so I can see how far above or below the control mean the version mean or each of its individual products is. Here is my reasoning:

- The vast majority of user ratings that make up my means are normally distributed. I checked using Kolmogorov-Smirnov and Shapiro-Wilk scores.

  - I checked everything that failed either of the tests with Q-Q plots and they are approximately normally distributed.
- My population is > 30

  - While each individual mean is circa 15 user rateings the total of the control is circa 105 and V1 is 105, I think this is correct.
- I can derive the Standard Deviation for

  - The individual mean scores
  - The combined mean scores of the Control and V1 shown below

[I also received an affirmative reply to a recent question I posted on whether or not a Z test was appropriate to this situation.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/229794/is-a-z-test-the-right-test-to-compare-the-mean-of-several-sub-groups-to-a-contr)

**My Hypothesis**

- H0 - Version 1 will have no effect on the mean user rating

  - The mean will not be significantly different to the control
- Ha - Version 1 will have an effect on the mean user rating

  - The mean will be significantly different to the control

I need to test this claim using alpha 0.05 or +1.96 to -1.96

**Z-Test**

I first took the mean ratings for each of the versions (from above)

```
Mean Ratings 4.74     -1.47     -1.88     7.77      4.08      6.90      13.66
```

And used SPSS to calculate Z-Scores for each

```
Control   = -.13054
Version 1 = -1.42611
Version 2 = -.72721
Version 3 = .50160
Version 4 = -.26823
Version 5 = .32009
Version 6 = 1.73041
```

This tells me that none of the common versions had a significant effect on the mean user ratings for the products.

My questions are:

**Are Z tests suitable for this sort of data analysis?** [(Since answered Yes)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/229794/is-a-z-test-the-right-test-to-compare-the-mean-of-several-sub-groups-to-a-contr)

**And if yes is my reasoning and my attempts correct?**

If anyone could point out any glaringly obvious mistakes or problems with my method it would be much appreciated

As always, any help is much appreciated.

**EDIT:**

I suspect that one issue is that I am including my control mean in my Z-Test calculation, which is skewing the results. But I am not sure how to undertake such a test when I am comparing it to a known mean...?

**Edit 2:**

In response to David Cs answer I am able to calculate the variance for each mean rating e.g. the Control = 105.999

```
Descriptive Statistics                      
          N   Minimum   Maximum   Mean      Std. Deviation    Variance
Control   7   -4.05     26.27     4.7371    10.29558          105.999
Valid N (listwise)  7
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a Z-Test, you should use the [T-Test for difference between means](http://www.stat.yale.edu/Courses/1997-98/101/meancomp.htm).  You should not use the Z-Test because you do not know the true variances for groups Control, V1, V2,...,V6.  The T-Test uses sample estimates for variances:

Z-Statistic:
$$Z = \frac{(\bar{X}_2 - \bar{X_1})}{\sqrt{\frac{\sigma^2_1}{n_1}+\frac{\sigma^2_2}{n_2}}}$$
T-Statistic:
$$T = \frac{(\bar{X}_2 - \bar{X_1})}{\sqrt{\frac{s^2_1}{n_1}+\frac{s^2_2}{n_2}}}$$

The two key differences are:

$\sigma^2_k$ – true population variance for group k

$s_k^2$ –$\frac{\sum^{n_k} (X_{ki} - \bar{X_k})^2}{n_k-1} $ sample variance from group k

Once you have computed your T-test statistic, you can compute the p-value [here](http://www.socscistatistics.com/pvalues/tdistribution.aspx) with the [Student's T-Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution) with
$$df = \min\big(n_1 - 1, n_2 - 1\big) $$

Or this can be done in R with the following commands:

```
t.test(Control,V1) 
t.test(Control,V2) 
t.test(Control,V3) 
t.test(Control,V4) 
t.test(Control,V5) 
t.test(Control,V6)
```

Comment: Thanks David, but I still think that a Z test is the most appropriate. Firstly because the sample population of each of my means is so high, circa 105 and secondly because I know the SD for each. I can also calculate the variance for each group, see Edit 2 above. However because I was not sure myself I also asked this question previously, the answer of which agrees that a Z test is the most appropriate. http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/229803/39684 Thanks for the help though, I will keep T-Tests for difference between means in the back pocket incase the Z-Tests do not work out

Comment: @Deepend A few things: (1) You ought to know the difference between the "true variance" and the "sample variance" of a population.  The "true variance" is the **intrinsic** level of variance throughout the entire population, while the "sample variance" is the variance calculated from just your sample.  This is an important distinction to make when deciding between the T-Test and Z-Test.  (2) As you indicated, with such large sample sizes (~105), the Z-Test will work in this case. [Here](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/z-test-vs-t-test-arunmozhi-ilango) is a good summary of how to choose

Comment: Thanks David, much appreciated and I will keep that in mind in future.